# Set a column value if it is NULL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to modify this query to set the value for the 'reason' column if it is empty then set the value to 'CUSTOM' (the third column across in the example below)

```
SELECT
    `t`.`myuser_id` AS `t0_c1`,
    IF (positive.reason IS NOT NULL,
        positive.reason,
        deduction.reason
    ) AS reason,
    `positive`.`achievement_id` AS `t1_c0`,
    `positive`.`reason` AS `t1_c2`,
    `deduction`.`reason` AS `t2_c2`
FROM
    `o_codes` `t`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `achievements` `positive` ON (`positive`.`achievement_id` = `t`.`order_product_id`)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `deductions` `deduction` ON (`deduction`.`deduction_id` = `t`.`order_product_id`)
WHERE
    t.myuser_id = 12345;
```

My output example...

```
t0_c1 | t0_c2  |   reason   | t1_c0 
1234  | 11481  | Good Stuff | (NULL)
1477  | 11482  |   (NULL)   | (NULL)
```

How can I alter this query so the second row which has a value of NULL for the reason column is set to 'CUSTOM' while taking into account the current IF statement is still required - any ideas?

Comment: You can use `IFNULL(colname,replacement_value)` on the column to replace the NULL value with something else

Comment: try COALESCE(positive.reason, deduction.reason, 'CUSTOM')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IF part should be

```
COALESCE(
IF (
positive.reason IS NOT NULL,
positive.reason,
deduction.reason
),'CUSTOM')
 AS reason,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IFNULL`:

```
IFNULL(expr1, 0)
```

**Reference**:

> If expr1 is not `NULL`, `IFNULL()` returns expr1; otherwise it returns expr2. '0' in this case.
>   `IFNULL()` returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

```
IFNULL(`positive`.`achievement_id`, 0) AS `t1_c0`,
```